# How can I attach a mouse event to a Run object in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, mouse

I can attach a mouse-click event to a TextBlock object like this:

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.Text = "click here";
tb.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(tb_MouseLeftButtonDown);
```

But I would like to instead attach the mouse-click to individual Run objects inside the TextBlock object so that various parts of the TextBlock are clickable, like this:

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.FontSize = 15;

Run run1 = new Run();
run1.Text = "This should be clickable";
run1.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(run1_MouseLeftButtonDown);

Run run2 = new Run();
run2.Text = " but not this.";

tb.Inlines.Add(run1);
tb.Inlines.Add(run2);
```

How can I attach a mouse event to a Run object?

Comment: You can't. Only thing you can try is to replace you Runs with separate TextBlocks.

Comment: This is the approach I'm taking: a WrapPanel with individual words as TextBlocks, which has some limitations but will do. Or is there a way to fill a TextBlock with TextBlocks so that you can still get things such as word-wrapping, justification, etc.? It doesn't seem that Inlines accepts TextBlocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this, but you can use hyperlink element instead.

Also there is another solution on my blog : http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2013/05/30/win8xaml-how-to-create-a-textblock-with-clickables-hyperlinks-in-it/

Regards.